# Use Wordpress Enqueue Array to Load Stylesheet Last

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want the modified child theme site-banner1.css stylesheet to load after the parent theme so it overwrites the parent file with the changes. I am using the enqueue array() to try and push site-banner1.css to the end of the queue by inputting the last style id (CSS from a plugin) into the array function. Here is the code from functions.php:

```
    <?php

    if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;


    if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):

    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( 
    get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array(  ) );
    }
    endif;

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { 

    $parent_style = 'tesseract-site-banner'; 

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, 
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/site-banner.css' ); 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/site-banner1.css', 

    array( $parent_style, 'tt-easy-google-font-styles')
    ); } 

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles',99999 );
```

Currently site-banner1.css is visible in the source code but it is not the last stylesheet to load and so the changes are not visible. The parent site-banner.css is still visible in the dev tools with the styles. By adding the last CSS id into the array can I force site-banner1.css to load after it, I think code is missing from the array but not sure what? If this is incorrect what is the way to force the sheet to load at the end of the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem using wp_deregister_style:

```
 <?php

    if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;


    if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):

    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( 
    get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array(  ) );
    }
    endif;

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_alta_styles', 200 );

    function load_alta_styles() {

    wp_dequeue_style( 'tesseract-site-banner' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'tesseract-site-banner' );



    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 
    '/site-banner1.css' );



}
```

Comment: There’s another option if you wanted to keep the theme script. In the final `array()` on wp_enqueue_style you can out the name of the other script (‘tesseract-site-banner’). This would have set that style sheet as a dependency for yours, ensuring that in the enqueue order your sheet follows any/all of the sheets in the array. [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)